# compress and store images in indexeddb

Tags: html, compression, indexeddb, image-compression, http-compression

I want to store images in indexeddb.

Would storing the image as a 'blob' occupy less space than as a Uint8ClampedArray?

What if i compressed the Uint8ClampedArray, would that occupy less space ?

Comment: What kind of images? Modern image formats like JPEG are already compressed so any re-compression might yield no benefits but might have increased CPU overhead instead.

Comment: PNG type images.